# The Gospel’s message for Constantine the Great

Tags: church-history, global-christianity

The case has been made regarding Jesus and Lazarus, that the fact that a person of substance (Jesus) should take an interest of a person such as Lazarus is perhaps a greater miracle than Lazarus’ health issues, that such an interest of the poor was not seen thousands of years before -including the Pharaohs - and thousands of years  later. One theory has been offered, that Jesus’ actions should all be seen in a political perspective, where his concern was to keep his followers united under the Roman threat.

Be that as it may. There is however a similar contradiction well known and documented of the same type on an almost-global scale, which certainly took place, well documented in many details: the transition to Christianity of the Roman Empire.
Seen from an angle, It is strange that such an unequal society world embrace the message of equality, love and care between all individuals in a society.
In The Decline and fall of the Roman Empire, Edward Gibbon mentions 5 reasons for the Roman acceptance of Christianity:

"I. The inflexible, and, if we may use the expression, the intolerant zeal of the Christians, derived, it is true, from the Jewish religion, but purified from the narrow and unsocial spirit which, instead of inviting, had deterred the Gentiles from embracing the law of Moses,

II.  The doctrine of a future life, improved by every additional circumstance which could give weight and efficacy to that important truth,

III.    The miraculous powers ascribed to the primitive church.

IV. The pure and austere morals of the Christians, and

V.  The union and discipline of the Christian republic, which gradually formed an independent and
increasing state in the heart of the Roman empire."

It is clear that the message of love for one another is not at the center in Gibbon’s notes.
Still, the conversion of Constantine the Great is very close in time to the first council of Nicaea, where Trinity is mentioned as a doctrine, i.e. the importance of Jesus and his views cannot be overlooked in Constantine’s belief so that, for example, the monotheistic property in
Christianity cannot be the dominant reason.

One can make the case that things are similar today, but there is a difference between keeping a tradition and creating one. The contradiction has become validated and visible in the case of slavery from time to time during the ages, but doesn’t explain the acceptance of the contradiction. Could the political values for Constantine the Great have shadowed what has become a more central message today?

Comment: welcome. There is no question in your title, and the question at the end is rather general. Could you specify the political values you refer to, as well as the more central message your refer to? Smaller problem, why to you consider Lazarus "poor" and Jesus "of substance?" Lazarus' family was wealthy enough to own a tomb and entertain guests. Are you possibly confusing the brother of Mary and Martha with the character in Luke 16:19, who happened to have the same name?

Comment: @dan Fefferman Thank you. I see your point. I actually thought he was poor.  I do imagine Jesus as some kind celebrity to use a modern term.  However, my main point is the contradiction between the equality message in Christianity and the acceptance within the Roman empire. Perhaps more relevant main question should be: How could the Romans embrace an equalitarian religion?